# com.esri.arcgisruntime.ArcGISRuntimeException: Object is already owned.: Already owned

Tags: android, arcgis, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-android-api

I have a switch to load satelite map in my app. It was working fine until some android update.

Now it throws an error and crashes the App. It shows ' com.esri.arcgisruntime.ArcGISRuntimeException: Object is already owned.: Already owned.'

I tried clearing the Layers before adding it again. I'm new in this space. kindly go through my code and see if I could do it in a better way.

**Code**

```
final ArcGISMapImageLayer PolyLayer = new ArcGISMapImageLayer("http://XXXXXX");
ArcGISTiledLayer tiledLayerBaseMap = new ArcGISTiledLayer("http://XXXXXX");

ServiceFeatureTable serviceFeatureTable = new ServiceFeatureTable("http://XXXXXX");
ServiceFeatureTable resZoneFeatureTable = new ServiceFeatureTable("http://XXXXXX");
ArcGISMap map = new ArcGISMap();


    public void switchMap() {   //calls on changw od switch
    mMapView.getGraphicsOverlays().remove(resGraphicsOverlay);
    mMapView.getGraphicsOverlays().remove(eventGraphicsOverlay);
    map.getOperationalLayers().clear();
    setupMap();
}


private void setupMap() {

    if (getBooleanFromSP("satMapON")) {
        Log.i("SAVL","SATMAPON");
        Basemap basemap = new Basemap(PolyLayer);
        map = new ArcGISMap(basemap);
        map.setBasemap(basemap);
        mMapView.getGraphicsOverlays().add(resGraphicsOverlay);
        mMapView.getGraphicsOverlays().add(eventGraphicsOverlay);
        mMapView.setMap(map);
        FeatureLayer featureLayer1 = new FeatureLayer(serviceFeatureTable);
        FeatureLayer resFeatureLayer1 = new FeatureLayer(resZoneFeatureTable);
        SimpleLineSymbol lineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.Style.SOLID, Color.rgb(252, 255,  164), 1);
        SimpleRenderer simpleRenderer = new SimpleRenderer(lineSymbol);
        resFeatureLayer1.setRenderer(simpleRenderer);
        map.getOperationalLayers().add(featureLayer1);
        map.getOperationalLayers().add(resFeatureLayer1);
        SimpleLineSymbol lineSymbol2 = new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.Style.SOLID, Color.rgb(0, 0, 255), 2);
        SimpleRenderer simpleRenderer2 = new SimpleRenderer(lineSymbol2);
        featureLayer1.setRenderer(simpleRenderer2);
        MapViewTouchListener mMapViewTouchListener = new MapViewTouchListener(this, mMapView);
        mMapView.setOnTouchListener(mMapViewTouchListener);
    }
    else if (!getBooleanFromSP("satMapON")) {
        Log.i("SAVL","SATMAPOFF");
        Basemap basemap = new Basemap(tiledLayerBaseMap);
        map = new ArcGISMap(basemap);
        map.setBasemap(basemap);
        mMapView.getGraphicsOverlays().add(resGraphicsOverlay);
        mMapView.getGraphicsOverlays().add(eventGraphicsOverlay);
        mMapView.setMap(map);
        FeatureLayer featureLayer2 = new FeatureLayer(serviceFeatureTable);
        FeatureLayer resFeatureLayer2 = new FeatureLayer(resZoneFeatureTable);
        SimpleLineSymbol lineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.Style.SOLID, Color.rgb(252, 255,  164), 1);
        SimpleRenderer simpleRenderer = new SimpleRenderer(lineSymbol);
        resFeatureLayer2.setRenderer(simpleRenderer);
        map.getOperationalLayers().add(featureLayer2);
        map.getOperationalLayers().add(resFeatureLayer2);
        SimpleLineSymbol lineSymbol2 = new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.Style.SOLID, Color.rgb(0, 0, 255), 2);
        SimpleRenderer simpleRenderer2 = new SimpleRenderer(lineSymbol2);
        featureLayer2.setRenderer(simpleRenderer2);
        MapViewTouchListener mMapViewTouchListener = new MapViewTouchListener(this, mMapView);
        mMapView.setOnTouchListener(mMapViewTouchListener);
    }

}
```

Error:

```
   --------- beginning of crash
2022-07-27 12:34:58.626 19151-19151/com.example.administrator.loccy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.administrator.loccy, PID: 19151
com.esri.arcgisruntime.ArcGISRuntimeException: Object is already owned.: Already owned.
    at com.esri.arcgisruntime.internal.jni.CoreFeatureLayer.nativeCreateWithFeatureTable(Native Method)
    at com.esri.arcgisruntime.internal.jni.CoreFeatureLayer.<init>(SourceFile:96)
    at com.esri.arcgisruntime.layers.FeatureLayer.a(SourceFile:4)
    at com.esri.arcgisruntime.layers.FeatureLayer.<init>(SourceFile:21)
    at com.dubaipolice.loccy.activities.MainActivity.setupMap(MainActivity.java:470)
    at com.dubaipolice.loccy.activities.MainActivity.switchMap(MainActivity.java:555)
    at com.dubaipolice.loccy.ResourceTypeDialogFragment$1.onClick(ResourceTypeDialogFragment.java:95)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7792)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16112)
    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:157)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7769)
    at android.view.View.access$3800(View.java:910)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30213)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```